# HW acceleration in KVM VM?

Tags: virtualization, 19.04, kvm-virtualization, hardware-acceleration

I have setup a Ubuntu 19.04 virtual machine (guest) on my Kubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Everything is working fine, but how do I enable HW-acceleration for video on the guest?

`vainfo` gives this error:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.4.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva    error,driver_name=(null)
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

I can set different options at Video: VGA, QXL, Virtio.
I have tried QXL, and now selected Virtio, because that's the only one that shows 3D acceleration, but alas no HW-decoding.

Integrated Intel 620, i7-8550U.

Answer (score 2):

for HW acceleration you'd need to pass some video card that is "less virtual" to the guest.

I have once outlined the [four contenders for pass-through](https://cpaelzer.github.io/blogs/006-mediated-device-to-pass-parts-of-your-gpu-to-a-guest/) options.
VFs won't help with GPUs and I'm not sure virtgl can do video acceleration (it couldn't in the past, but is the easiest to set up - maybe worth a try). So it seems you are down to `mediated devices` or `GPU pci passthrough`?

My link above has some info about the rather new mediated devices, if you choose to use GPU passthrough you'll find plenty of [guides](https://blog.zerosector.io/2018/07/28/kvm-qemu-windows-10-gpu-passthrough/), the linked one is just the top result a search engine gave me and it seems ok (to me).

Comment: @Christain. Thx, yes I saw guides about setups with a dedicated GPU, which is not the case here.  I'm not sure if the guest can still use the GPU with PCI pass-through. Should give `mediated devices` a go, but because my guest is 18.04 LTS, I'm not sure it will be successful.